# Google recaptcha not working to local virtual hosts

Tags: recaptcha

I'm using wamp server on my laptop and using virtual hosts to websites. I added google recaptcha for signup forms but it is giving error "ERROR for site owner:
Invalid domain for site key". 
How we use the reCaptcha to virtual host ?